# Local ReactJS App on WAMP server

Tags: php, ajax, reactjs, npm, wamp

I recently started a reactjs webapp. Im writing it locally on a wamp server. I created it in a directory and copied the directory over to the 'www' folder of the wamp server. The wamp server is running fine. When I run npm start the site comes live at localhost:3000, it navigates to my php file, however it returns all the php code, instead of executing it. When I navigate directly to the PHP file, the code executes fine. My question is, how can i locally run PHP in my reactJS App.

My AJAX call (successful):

```
$.ajax({
  url: this.props.url,
  method: "POST",
  data: "userID="+this.props.user,
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({data: data});
  }.bind(this),
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
  }.bind(this)
});
```

My PHP code is simply right now, Ive been trying to test if i can get anything to work, so for right now it is:

```
<?php
 echo "Hello World";
?>
```

Here is my Index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

var $ = require ('jquery');
var retrieveCardsPHP = require('./getStartUp/retreiveCards.php');
var userID = 1; //write function to get UserID

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

var Cards = React.createClass({
  loadCardsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      method: "POST",
      data: "userID="+this.props.user,
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) {
    var comments = this.state.data;
    var newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
    this.setState({data: newComments});
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: comment,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadCardsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadCardsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>

      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Cards url={retrieveCardsPHP} user={userID} pollInterval={5000} />,
  document.getElementById('Page1')
);
```

Much of this code was taken from the tutorial, and I am trying to modify it.
All i want to do is run the app locally without creating a build everytime.
Thank you.

Comment: What does your npm start script look like?

Comment: @shadymoses Where can I find the npm start script? Im new to reactJS, thank you

Comment: npm scripts will be in your package.json file at the "scripts" key. If there's not a "start" key there then it's just running your main file. You can also find out which file that is in your package.json. It defaults to index.js.

Comment: @shadymoses It did default to Index.js, I updated my main question to include it

Comment: I see at least one issue where you're trying to require a php file in node:

    ```var retrieveCardsPHP = require('./getStartUp/retreiveCards.php');```

That's not going to work like you think. Node is a js environment and it won't execute php. You don't want to require a php file in node.

Comment: What role exactly are you wanting php to play in your react app? A service layer for your data? Rendering html that includes your react app? You mention that the code is from a tutorial, but don't say which one. Any extra information you can give will be very helpful

Comment: I just want to achieve server-side connectivity while using react as a front end. I have been attempting to use PHP for my back end., I am trying to set up this environment locally on my WAMP server. The tutorial I was using is [link](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorialhttps://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial). I would like react to simply display the user interface, and call server-side functions to retrieve data and update the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep components between routes using react-router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301044/keep-components-between-routes-using-react-router)