# Creating a ReactJS Portal

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I am developing a simple modal and some tooltips. I wanted to understand a little about portals so decided to have a go at making one. I have the following code:

```
            const Portal = React.createClass({
                render() { return null },
                portalElement: null,
                componentDidMount() {
                    let p = this.props.portalId && document.getElementById(this.props.portalId);
                    if(!p) {
                        let p = document.createElement('div');
                        p.id = this.props.portalId;
                        document.body.appendChild(p);
                    }
                    this.portalElement = p;
                    this.componentDidUpdate();
                },
                componentWillUnmount() {
                    document.body.removeChild(this.portalElement);
                },
                componentDidUpdate() {
                    render(<div {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</div>, this.portalElement);
                }
            });
```

When I run this code, I get the following error in console:

```
Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

My understanding is that it can not find an element where to mount this in body. I have tried adding  to index.html but this still hasn't solved it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802179/how-to-create-a-react-modalwhich-is-append-to-body-with-transitions

Comment: @GinoLlerena Thanks for quick response. I followed that tutorial - thats how I got the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be var p = ... and not let p = ...