# How to blur background of webpage and make it not interactable in certain areas?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm basically trying to implement a popup that blurs the background and makes it so that the user can't touch the buttons and other components in the background.

Comment: try using backdrop-filter and pointer in css !

Comment: Likely [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802179/how-to-create-a-react-modalwhich-is-append-to-body-with-transitions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this class on your main element container to blur the whole background

```css
.blured {
  filter: blur(2px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}
```

And add `pointer-events: none;` on your modal or popup

Answer (score 4):

You can disable the whole div by using css.

```
#div-id{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will disable all the elements inside the div.
If you want the blur effect you can add `opacity: 0.2;` to the div css.

Answer (score 1):

By using css  `backdrop-filter` property and `pointer-events` you can achieve what u need .. see example below

```css
 
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .disabled{
     pointer-events: none;
     color : grey;
    }

    .modal {
        position: fixed;
        inset: 0;
        isolation: isolate;
        background-color: rgba(19, 128, 119, 0.5);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .popup {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 400px;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        padding: 1rem;
    }
    .blur{
        position: absolute;
        inset: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        backdrop-filter: blur(0.2rem);
    }
```

```html
  
<div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid dolorum illo, non incidunt earum natus neque architecto a autem maxime voluptatibus tempora minima, provident expedita quidem cumque ab. Error, tenetur?
</div>
<div class="modal">
    <div class="blur"></div>
    <div class="popup">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi quam architecto minima nihil aliquid quis unde
        illo mollitia iure. Quia.
        <br /> <br /> <br />
        <a href="#" class="disabled">
            I am a disabled link !
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

> References : [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) and [backdrop-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter).

> Note: Also remember using pointer events doesn't means you can't use keyboard to focus.. To prevent keyboard tab focus you might need to use [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute on the link

Comment: Thankyou. Now is it possible to do this from a button inside of the 'text' div? I'm using react right now and the button i have is very far down the tree.

Comment: @Trunks159  Yes it is possible ! Just give the button a class and then you can style it accordingly..

Answer (score 1):

```
    body{
    position:relative;
    ///rest of your style
    }
    .backdrop {//create a div inside body // <div class".backdrop"></div>
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      z-index: 1;
      backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    }
    .backdrop:enabled { //here we have disable all pevnts
      pointer-events: none;
    }
```