# ReactJS Modal Component

Tags: reactjs

How do you create a ReactJS component that reaches multiple levels up the component/DOM hierarchy?

A good example of this is a Modal. I want to trigger and control the modal from a child nested way down in my app, but a Modal requires that the DOM be much higher, most likely all the way up as a child of the document body.

I'm considering a "portal" pattern, as described here: https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-training/blob/gh-pages/lessons/05-wrapping-dom-libs.md#portals

FakeRainBrigand even wraps the pattern up nicely in a mixing in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26789089/586181

This feels like a hack to me. Great if you want to use a non-react library like jquery-ui, but without that need breaking out of react just to render a react component somewhere else in the DOM seems like overkill. Is there a more "React" way of achieving this?

Thanks

Comment: The "best" is very subjective and as written, this seems more discussion oriented than is usually a good fit for StackOverflow. It's always just JavaScript ... so you can manipulate the DOM as needed.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I've edited in an attempt to be less subjective. And yes, I could just edit the DOM directly, or do a dozen other things. But is there a "React way" of doing it, is the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll leave this best to the react documentation.  If you must have buried React elements that need to communicate with other elements outside of their Parent Child or possibly even grandparent than see the below.

> For communication between two components that don't have a
>   parent-child relationship, you can set up your own global event
>   system. Subscribe to events in componentDidMount(), unsubscribe in
>   componentWillUnmount(), and call setState() when you receive an event.

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

Comment: I missed that in the docs. Thanks! Seems odd that they would recommend a global system when one of their core tenets is modularity.

Comment: yeah I agree with you.  Trying to summarize an alternative in my head though, I can't come up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a library to help with this.  I avoid the DOM insertion hacks used by Portal strategies out there and instead make use of context based registries to pass along components from a source to a target.

My implementation makes use of the standard React render cycles.  The components that you teleport/inject/transport don't cause a double render cycle on the target - everything happens synchronously.

The API is also structured in a manner to discourage the use of magic strings in your code to define the source/target.  Instead you are required to explicitly create and decorate components that will be used as the target (Injectable) and the source (Injector).  As this sort of thing is generally considered quite magical I think explicit Component representation (requiring direct imports and usage) may help alleviate confusion on where a Component is being injected.

You can completely use my library to bind a ModalComponent to a root level component that you decorate with the Injectable helper.  I plan on adding an example of this use case soon.  It even supports natural props pass throughs, and all the various component types i.e. stateless/class.

See https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-injectables for more info.

Comment: Looks awesome. I'll give it a try.

Comment: No problem.  Shout if you get stuck.  Feedback is appreciated. <3